# Sorting columns left to right in Google Sheets ascending order

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet in google sheets and I need sort columns left to right based on every other column.

here's what I tried so far:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange("A3:J4").getValues();
  
  const transpose = m => m[0].map((x,i) => m.map(x => x[i]))

  var [col1, col2, ...etc] = transpose(data);
  var table = transpose([col1, col2, ...etc.sort()]);

  sheet.getRange(15,1,table.length,table[0].length).setValues(table)
}
```

But it skips the first two columns and also the sorting isn't accurate, I'm trying to sort dates from recent to older
Any ideas how to fix this?

here's a screenshot of the table to be sorted and the aim is to sort dates from recent to old horizontally from left to right
[Here is the screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsJqn.png)

Thanks

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expectr as the image?

Comment: I just updated the question with a screenshot, I hope that explains my question

Comment: Thank you for replying. Is your showing image your sample input situation? If my understanding is correct, can you provide your expected sample output situation? Do you want to sort only row 3? And, in your Spreadsheet, the date is the date object? By the way, in your showing script, it seems that you want to retrieve the values from "A1:H2" by `sheet.getRange("A1:H2").getValues()`. In this case, when your showing image is used, the date is not retrieved. So, I cannot understand your question. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: I updated the screenshot, sorting both rows 3 and 4 based on the dates on row 3 from recent dates to older ones

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. From your updated question, I thought that I might be able to understand your question. So, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Frontlinemedical Your "Thank you" post was deleted. If the answer helped, you can "thank" or "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark button on the left of their answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to achieve the following conversion. (The following image is from your question.)

  [image]

When I saw your script, at `var [col1, col2, ...etc] = transpose(data);`, all columns are not used. And, at `...etc.sort()`, unfortunately, I thought that in this case, the values are not sorted. So, in order to achieve your goal, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getRange("A3:J4");
  const data = range.getValues();
  const transpose = m => m[0].map((x, i) => m.map(x => x[i]));
  const t = transpose(data).filter(e => e.join(""));
  const res = t.sort(([a], [b]) => a.getTime() < b.getTime() ? 1 : -1).flatMap(e => [e, Array(e.length).fill("")]);
  range.setValues(transpose(res));
}
```

- When this script is run, the above conversion is obtained.

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that the values of "A3:J3" are the date object in your actual Spreadsheet. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> That works perfectly with one small problem, it only works if all columns in the range has data but if one column is empty, it will throw an error: Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range.

From your provided sample image, I couldn't notice that the empty columns are existing. In this case, how about the following sample script? But, unfortunately, I cannot know your expected situation for the sheet including the empty columns. So, the following sample script is due to my guess.

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getRange("A3:J4");
  const data = range.getValues();
  const transpose = m => m[0].map((x, i) => m.map(x => x[i]));
  const t = transpose(data);
  let res = t.filter(e => e.join("")).sort(([a], [b]) => a.getTime() < b.getTime() ? 1 : -1).flatMap(e => [e, Array(e.length).fill("")]);
  if (res.length < t.length) {
    res = [...res, ...Array(t.length - res.length).fill(["", ""])];
  }
  range.setValues(transpose(res));
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly with one small problem, it only works if all columns in the range has data but if one column is empty, it will throw an error: Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range.

Comment: @Frontline medical Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, from your provided sample image, I couldn't that the empty columns are included. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would like to study it more. For your additional request, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? But, I cannot know your expected situation for your new request. So, if I misunderstood your goal again, I apologize again.